# Getting ApplicationId and AdUnitID from new pubcenter website

Tags: windows-phone-7

MS PubCenter has updated their website to modern. I wanted to add ADS to my WP application I created new one banner 480 80. I found (I not sure) appunitid but i cant find application id Where is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose the application from pubcenter and then scroll down the website and then to right you can see application id and unit id